# django-admin-bootstrapped conflicts with django-autocomplete-light with error: $("[title]").tooltip() is not a function

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm setting up a django site using django-autocomplete-light (v3); however, when I add django-admin-bootstrapped, the following error occurs:

> `$('[title]').tooltip();` tooltip is not a function.

I installed `dal` and `dal_select2` before `django-admin-bootstrapped` and `django.contrib.admin` in `settings.py` as follow:

```
'dal',
'dal_select2',
'django_admin_bootstrapped',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

It appears to me that, `django-autocomplete-light` has its own *jQuery* and somehow overrides the `django-admin` original *jQuery*. It might be a *jQuery* loading issue, because when I run `collectstatic`, I can clearly see a new *jquery.min.js* and a *jquery.init.js* added by `django-autocomplete-light`.

But this is not an issue at all until I add `django-admin-bootstrapped` which breaks the page loading with that error.

In Chrome Dev Tools Network tab, I can see both django admin and django-autocomplete-light jquery being loaded and that appears to be the problem.

How to solve this issue?
How to control which scripts get included by vendors in `collecstatic`?

Do I have to manually delete or edit generated static files by `collecstatic` (which might not work when deploying to `heroku` for instance)?

Or is there a better way to control what `collectstatic` process and create some post processing function to solve this conflict?